# why do we need to set the time as i*time in the setTimeout() and not just time

Tags: javascript

I cant understand how and why cant i use a specific set time like `2000` to iterate over some numbers with a delay of 2 seconds instead of `i*2000` in `setTimeout()`

```
function timer() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, i * 2000);
    }
}

timer();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you use the static value `2000` then all 10 values will be logged to the console simultaneously after 2 seconds.  The intent instead is to log a value *every* two seconds.  So the first log is at 2000, then 4000, then 6000, etc.

> why cant i use a specific set time like 2000 to iterate over some numbers

You may be looking for `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.  Something like this:

```js
let x = 1;
let i = setInterval(function () {
  console.log(x++);
  if (x > 10) {
    clearInterval(i);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Conceptually the two approaches are meant to accomplish the same thing.  The version in the question does so with a kind of artificial interval by creating a finite set of multiple staggered timeouts, whereas this version creates and clears an interval.

Answer (score 2):

This is in a loop so it progressively adds longer delays before running the callback hence the scale value `i`. Of course this could be solved with a `setInterval` and a `clearInterval`.